# How do I remove words in a file from a list of words in another .txt file using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to remove words in a list (a .txt file) using sed, but it is not working correctly.
The output file removes the words it should remove and also parts of words it shouldn't remove.

This is the code that I've tried:

```
sed -E 's/('"$(tr '\n' '|' < listOfWords.txt )"')//gI' file.txt > output.txt
```

Example of input:

```
I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce. I do not want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that say they do something and do not deliver.  

Can you please add audio samples with text you've converted? I'd love to see the end results.

Thanks!
```

Expected output:

```
would love try hear sample audio app can produce. do want purchase, because ve purchased many apps say do something do deliver.  

Can please add audio samples text ve converted? d love see end results.
```

list of words sample:

```
...
I
to
or
the
your
not
so
that
they
and
you
with
Thanks
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for adding your efforts in your question(keep it up). Please do add samples of input and expected output in your question so that we get better understanding of it, thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you want to be anchoring your regex so it only matches at word boundaries. Is this GNU sed, or do we need to stick to only standard-mandated functionality?

Comment: A sample `listOfWords.txt` is also needed to reproduce the actual output (and test a proposed answer against desired output). Ideally, examples should comply with the [mre] spec -- being the _shortest possible thing_ that demonstrates the problem when used without changes. If you only need code to remove two words to show the problem, building a 2-word list and example input/output around it helps keep things terse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\<` and `\>` in your `sed` expression prevents items that don't start and end at word boundaries from being removed. Be aware that this is a GNUism -- a baseline POSIX-standard `sed` may not support it.

Using shell functions instead of files in the below reproducer so it can be copied-and-pasted to test without needing to create data files first:

```
getListOfWords() {
  printf '%s\n' I to or the your not so that they and you with Thanks
}

getInFile() {
  cat <<EOF
I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce. I do not want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that say they do something and do not deliver.  

Can you please add audio samples with text you've converted? I'd love to see the end results.

Thanks!
EOF
}

sed -E 's/\<('"$(tr '\n' '|' < <(getListOfWords) )"')\>//gI' <(getInFile)
```

...emits as output:

```
 would love  try  hear  sample audio  app can produce.  do  want  purchase, because 've purchased  many apps  say  do something  do  deliver.  

Can  please add audio samples  text 've converted? 'd love  see  end results.

!
```

...which matches your intended output with the sole exception that that stated intended output has some extra behavior around removal of punctuation that the original code makes no attempt to implement.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to pipe sed commands to sed using `sed -f-`:

`sed 's|^|s/|; s|$|\\s*//gI|' listOfWords.txt | sed -f- file.txt > output.txt`

This turns listOfWords.txt into sed replacement commands and pipes them to sed:

- replaces the start of each line in listOfWords with `s/`
- replaces the end of each line in listOfWords with `\s*//gI`
- This results in `s/word\s*//gI` foreach `word` in listOfWords
- pipe the list of replacements to `sed -f- file.txt`, where `-` means "stdin"

Somewhat similar in concept to OP's attempt with `tr`, but using only sed as enabled by `sed -f-`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl alternative. The first argument needs to be the listOfWords file.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {open F, shift; $w=join("|", <F>); $w=~s/\n//g;}
          s/\b($w)\b\s*//g;'  /tmp/listOfWords.txt  /tmp/file.txt
```

The `\s*` at the end of the regex let's it also remove trailing spaces to avoid multiple consecutive spaces.

The output with your example is:

> ```
> would love try hear sample audio app can produce. do want purchase, because 've purchased many apps say do something do deliver.  
>
> Can please add audio samples text 've converted? 'd love see end results.
>
> !
> ```

If you also want to remove the `'` after "I" and "you", you could add `I'` and `you'` at the start of your word list file.

Answer (score 1):

If GNU `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s input.txt < <(
  printf '%s\n' ',s/^/\\b/' ',s/$/\\b/' '1,$-1s/$/\\|/' '1;$j' 's/^/,s\//' 's/$/\/\/g/' '$a' ,p w . ,p Q  |
  ed -s listOfWords.txt
)
```